# Connecting to oracle db from python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

We are connecting to oracle from python using cx_oracle package.
But the user_id, password and SID details are hardcoded in that.
My question is, is there any way to create a Datasource kind of thing? Or how we will deploy such python script sin production?

The database is in a Linux box and python is installed in another Linux box(Weblogic server is also installed in this Linux box).

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@127.0.0.1/orcl')
print con.version
```

Expectation is :

Can we deploy python in a production instance?
If yes how can we connect to the database by hiding the DB credentials?

Comment: What about storing the credentials in some file and reading the values from that file? Will that be acceptable for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of 'external authentication', for example a wallet.  See the cx_Oracle documentation https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-using-external-authentication

In summary:

- create a wallet with mkstore which contains the username/password credentials.
- copy the wallet to the machines that are running Python
- make sure no bad people can access the wallet
- configure Oracle Net files to point to the wallet
- your scripts  would connect like

  ```
  connection = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn="mynetalias", encoding="UTF-8")
  ```

  or

  ```
  pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(externalauth=True, homogeneous=False, dsn="mynetalias",
                   encoding="UTF-8")
  pool.acquire()
  ```